# Dataweave: Cannot coerce String to Datetime

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

So I need to transform this String : `"2023-01-30T15:00:00+0100"` to Datetime in order to send to SF.

I've tried like this :

`StartDateTime: payload.planDate as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"}` and instead of "DateTime" , "LocalDateTime".
None of them seem to work.

Both give me this error :
`Cannot coerce String (2023-01-30T15:00:00+0100) to DateTime, caused by: Text '2023-01-30T15:00:00+0100'`

Could you help me transform the String to DateTime?

Expected Result : `"2023-01-30T15:00:00+0100"`

Comment: Not really your question but...you should be very careful with LocalDateTime unless you understand why you need it. It throws away the time zone information, which is hardly ever what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data is a DateTime because it includes a timezone. Your format is incorrect because it has milliseconds and the input has not. Removing that should be OK.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var planDate="2023-01-30T15:00:00+0100"
---
planDate as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"}
```

Output:

```json
"2023-01-30T15:00:00+0100"
```

Note that the output is a string because the output format is JSON and JSON doesn't has a date type. If you output other in a different format you will see the DateTime output. If you intend to use the resulting DateTime for calculations in the flow then `application/java` is the best output format for performance.